# Proof that 4-velocity is normalized in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, geodesics

Whenever I try to find an explanation for the normalization of the four-velocity

\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dx^\nu}{d\tau}=-1
\end{equation}
I'm always shown a proof in Minkowski space plus the argument that to generalize a flat spacetime formula to curved spacetime one simply replaces $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ with $g_{\mu \nu}$ I understand this conceptually but my question is: Is there a way to prove that 4-velocity is normalized without recurring to flat space?

Comment: It seems to me, that if tau is proper time, this is true by definition. If it represents some other parametrisation of the path, it need not hold.

Comment: That normalization follows from $-d\tau^2\equiv g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity vector at any point lives in the tangent space at that point, and the tangent space *is* flat.